# Css Cascade breaking for guru

Tags: css

I need some help on a obvious cascade problem... not so obvious

I have to override some css child style, with another style of the same weight (here 012) , without moving it's order definition in the css sheet...

Here is a clear example in Jsfiddle :
[Go to JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54nUG/4/)

So the style has to :

- don't add a third selector (just modify the two given)
- keep the order in the style definition (green before red)
- keep both selector the same, if you change the green selector, the a selector have to be the same.
- the real HTML is deaper as the one provided (the a is not just inside a div child)

For example, if `.green div a` becomes :

```
.green > * a
```

then the red selector have to be :

```
.red > * a
```

The second link must be exactly the same selector (except the color name)

EDIT : the Why i have to do it that way :

In my site you can customise your theme (color). But when you look at another user profil, you see his profil in his own color theme, but inside your theme. so green theme can be embedded inside a red theme... there is more than 10 theme, so i can't style every combinaison (green > red, red > green, blue > red, etc...)

Comment: I must ask the obvious, why do it this way???

Comment: I'd like to know the same...

Comment: Maybe a JavaScript/jQuery solution is the way to go.  For some reason, the style sheets have to be a certain way and the order of things go contrary to the normal cascade behavior.  A JS solution might give you a more stable solution instead of a cutting edge convolution of CSS selectors.

Comment: This sounds more like a riddle than a question. What I am seeing is that you are saying that everything has to stay the same but produce different results, which as far as I could tell you doesn't happen..

Comment: In my site you can customise your theme (color). But when you look at another user profil, you see his profil in his own color theme, but inside your theme. so green theme can be embedded inside a red theme...  there is more than 10 theme, so i can't style every combinaison

Comment: @BrettWeber : It's not a riddle, it's  a true and simple problem...

Comment: Would you be willing to use something like SCSS? Also, you ever have more than one theme nested deeper than another theme?

Comment: @Marc Audet : no, i only have one theme nested max. What is SCSS ?

Comment: @CtrlX: "How will you break this cascade... Will it breaks you ;) ?" The way you phrase it makes it sound like a riddle.

Comment: @BoltClock: perhaps, but it was more a sort of funny way to ask. So joke is forbidden on stackoverflow... i'll remember

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have to modify both rules exactly the same, yes?  All you need to do is look at the HTML and figure out how you can select the anchor so they are more specific. In your example, you can see that the HTML has both `.red` and `.green` are one div away from the anchor they want to style, so simply change them both to strictly style an anchor that is one only div away. Now, `.red` won't touch `.green`'s anchor, because it's two `div`s away:

```
.green > div > a { color:green;}
.red > div > a { color:red;}
```

Here's the jsFiddle for your example: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/54nUG/5/

---

**Updated with OP's Edits**

One thing you can try is to have a consistent themeing convention (this can be a separate attribute, or a prefix). Take this CSS:

```
.theme-green a,
[class*="theme-"] .theme-green a {color:green;}
.theme-red a,
[class*="theme-"] .theme-red a {color:red;}
```

Assuming all themes start with `theme-` we can use the above to override the styles. Here, line 3 overrides line 1 (as usual), but the new line 2 overrides line 3, which is what you want (green theme inside red theme). Of course, the downside is you're doubling your CSS code.

Here's the new jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/54nUG/10/

Comment: Yes but the HTML provided is only as an example. the real one is more complex and we dont know the full depth of the nested a ...

Comment: @CtrlX I mean, I can keep solving your puzzle for you, but if you keep changing your requirements, how is there an end? :)

Comment: i'm not changing it, but i just can't put the whole HTML of the whole page, i've simplified the problem and i just give you precision here

Comment: @CtrlX In your new example, you could do `.green > div:not([class]) a {...}` and `.red > div:not([class]) a {...}` as in http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/54nUG/8/

Comment: it's the closed answer but it's work only if no element between the '.green' and the 'a' has a style, witch is not possible :(

Comment: @CtrlX I've updated with something you can try. You'll have to modify your classes slightly so you can catch an overall themed element using the attribute selector.

Comment: Right answer, it's a shame that i have to had a selector for each color, but i think there no better solution :(

Answer (score 0):

`.green div a { color:green!important;}`

Comment: You should really only use `!important` for debugging. The point of CSS is that it's cascading and using this technique breaks that.

Comment: the content of the style have to be the same, so if you add !important on green, you have to put it in red

Answer (score 0):

you can add a more specific selector:

```
.red div.green div a { color:green;}
.red div a { color:red;}
```

Comment: @CtrlX Regarding this answer, this is a good read on CSS specificity: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: The selector have to be the same. If you put this to green to, it doesnt work

Comment: dude, you need to rethink this stylesheet design.

Comment: yes, that why i'm here (I have put clarification on the "why i do it that way")